# Prevent my process from receiving messages from another process

Tags: c, winapi

A process can use `PostMessage()` to send a message to another process (for example: sending a `WM_CLOSE` message to Notepad).

My question is: can I prevent my process from receiving messages from another process? For example: if some process tried to send me a `WM_CLOSE` message, can I prevent this message from being received by my message queue?

Comment: Can you not just ignore it in your WNDPROC switch list?

Comment: @Martin James I don't mean just not receiving a `WM_CLOSE` message, I mean not receiving any message from another process.

Comment: The only thing that can prevent this is UIPI which stops lower integrity processes sending some messages to higher ones. Otherwise there's no way.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Can a user somehow distinguish, what process is the message from?

Comment: Just relax and stop worrying about it. Rather than fretting about the receipt, stop sending the messages.

Comment: Yeah - what is sending these annoying messages anyway?

Comment: @Martin James I asked this question because I want to understand how Windows messages work and not because some crazy process is sending messages to my process :-)

Comment: You are using *sending* and *posting* interchangeably, although they are very different procedures. While you cannot discern, whether a posted message originated from another process, you can at least know, whether a sent message was sent from another thread, by calling [InSendMessageEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644942.aspx). Apart from that, stackoverflow is about **practical** programming problems. This doesn't appear to be very practical.

Comment: You could hook the PostMessageA/W function of other processes via dll injection, and discard the message if it is for your process from another. @Jonathan Potter: there is always some way ;)

Comment: @fassl: I'm sure you have a reliable solution to deal with `HWND_BROADCAST` as well. Let's hear it.

Comment: @llnspactable didn't think of that first. Can't we get all top windows and childs of them and monitor newly created windows to maintain a list of handles to post the message to?

Comment: some messages do not need parameters like WM_CLOSE, in this case, it is easy to filter alien messages by checking if wParam or lParam (or even both) equals to zero, when you want to send WM_CLOSE to your self just set any of these parameter to 1 for example. @llnspactable don't downvote me please :). this is just a suggestion.

Comment: @milevyo What about when I click on the **X** button? I can't control the values of `wParam` and `lParam` in this case.

Comment: what about using GetCurspos, WindowFromPoint and WM_NCHITTEST?